# Cisco VPN stopped working

Tags: wireless, networking, vpn, cisco

I'm using the Cisco VPN Anyconnect client to connect my home computer to work. When I use my personal router it works fine, but when I use the free wifi that comes with my apartment it stops working. This happens on both my desktop (11.10) and netbook (netbook remix).

Does anyone know why?

EDIT: I'm not sure what information is useful here (dmesg doesn't seem to display anything useful) but here's a session:

```
~> ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
~> dhclient
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What happens when it "stops working"?

Comment: @ændrük: I've updated the question a bit; basically nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the free wi-fi is not allowing the VPN connection to pass. If you normally have to sign-in or 'agree to terms' on the free wireless you should do this first before trying to use the VPN.

Comment: I can browse the internet normally before I turn on VPN, so I'm not sure if this is it

Comment: if you are able to browse then it is not that you have ti sign in or agree to terms. They may still block VPNs. Can you talk to them about the issue? If it works on your router it is properly configured.

Comment: Do you know exactly what they would be blocking? Some port? A protocol?

Comment: They could have an application aware filter. It would be rare, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall using-

```
sudo /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh
```

Then reinstall the Cisco VPN client

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the host network that has something blocking. But, maybe you could try  the FOSS openconnect (in place of the cisco anyconnect client) in Ubuntu to connect to the Cisco Anyconnect capable router:

`sudo apt-get install openconnect && sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect`

Then reboot, then use the network applet to create a new vpn connection.

I made a writeup about it here:
http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/06/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-to-cisco.html

Comment: openconnect also mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129477/server-certificate-problem-with-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client