# Server certificate problem with Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client

Tags: 12.04, vpn, cisco

When I try to connect using the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client, I receive this error:

[image: Connection attempt has failed due to server certificate problem.]

> Connection attempt has failed due to server certificate problem.

I happened to have this problem in my previous Ubuntu 11.10 installation. That time I could fix it using some tutorials on the internet (I don't remember which one). Basically, they suggested installing 4-5 packages and then some `ln -s`. But this time none of them are working. Can anyone help me step by step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can confirm that this problem exists. Anyconnect client worked fine with 11.10 but stops working with 12.04. Old trick with links to firefox libraries does not work anymore. I end up using OpenConnect.

Installation: http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/06/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-to-cisco.html
Routing: http://www.redips.net/linux/vpn-client-and-routing-2/

More details on Cisco Anyconnect problem:

As you can see from log: user was able to login, but Anyconnect client still failed to establish vpn connection.

Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client (version 2.5.3055) .

```
state: Connecting
notice: Establishing VPN session...
notice: Checking for profile updates...
notice: Checking for product updates...
notice: Checking for customization updates...
notice: Checking for localization updates...
state: Connecting
notice: Establishing VPN session...
notice: Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
state: Disconnecting
notice: Disconnect in progress, please wait...
state: Disconnected
notice: VPN session ended.
error: The certificate on the secure gateway is invalid. A VPN connection will not be established.

error: AnyConnect was not able to establish a connection to the specified secure gateway. Please try connecting again.
notice: Connection attempt has failed.
state: Disconnected
```

Comment: Thanks. It was super easy. apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome

Comment: Tried getting AnyConnect to work with self-signed but I could not make it work.

OpenConnect for NetorkManager worked right away though!

Answer (score 12):

The following fix worked for me - fresh install of 12.04 LTS 32bit (with Firefox 12). Installed the AnyConnect client, then tried to run it.

Got this message:

> AnyConnect cannot confirm it is connected to your secure gateway. The
>   local network may not be trustworthy. Please try another network.

Checked syslog in Ubuntu. Lots of this sort of stuff:

```
CERTSTORE_ERROR_CERT_NOT_FOUND The /opt/.cisco/certificates/ca/ directory was not found
```

Created /`.cisco/certificates/ca` directories in `/opt` using `sudo`

```
cd /opt
sudo mkdir .cisco
cd .cisco/
sudo mkdir certificates
cd certificates/
sudo mkdir ca
```

We use Globalsign as our certificate authority. So I just copied all the Globalsign .pem files from `/etc/ssl/certs`. If you don't know your provider, you could just copy everything.

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/Global* /opt/.cisco/certificates/ca
```

or if CA is unknown

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/cd /etc/ssl/cert/* /opt/.cisco/certificates/ca
```

I was able to start the AnyConnect client and connect to the VPN

Hope this helps.

Comment: `ln -s /etc/ssl/certs ~/.cisco/certificates/ca` works as well

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. However, I think the command for copying everything should be
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/Global* /opt/.cisco/certificates/ca

Comment: The solution worked for me.  

I don't know if any of the detail here makes an impact.  I just list additional details that worked for me.

The directory /opt/.cisco/certificates/ca already existed.  So, I used Google Chrome to go to VPN server.  Clicked on its certificate and exported root certificate with "Base64-encoded ASCII, single certificate" option.  I saved the file with PEM extension.  VPN client picked the change without need for restart.

Answer (score 4):

Copying the certificates did not work, but a combination of the two ended up working for me:

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs/cd
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/Global* .
```

Then ...

```
sudo apt-get install firefox 
cd /opt/cisco/vpn/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/firefox/lib*.so .
```

... and bingo. I can log into work now :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it.

```
cd /opt
sudo mkdir .cisco
cd .cisco/
sudo mkdir certificates
cd certificates/
sudo mkdir ca
```

I then found out which certificate authority we use, which was COMODO, found a site that uses this CA, downloaded it with a browser and put it into the

```
/opt/.cisco/certificates/ca/ directory
```

voila!

Answer (score 2):

I tried these solutions listed above and none of them helped. But when I tried some of these solutions below having to do with the firefox libraries, I had success!

[Override certificate error in Cisco AnyConnect Client on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit](http://www.codemarvels.com/2012/05/override-certificate-error-in-cisco-anyconnect-client-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit/)

[Cisco AnyConnect in 64bit Ubuntu Linux](http://scottlinux.com/2011/01/31/cisco-anyconnect-in-64bit-ubuntu-linux/)

I can't say which is the BEST solution, but I followed the directions on both of these sites and had success. Perhaps you can find a solution that works for you. If you know which one is the best, please let us know which variable solved the problem immediately. All I know is that after making some of these changes, I finally got my Cisco Anyconnect VPN working. I am Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. see here:
http://www.oit.uci.edu/security/vpn/vpn-lin.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Link is now broken

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that you have Firefox installed and are able to successfully launch it. If all is successful, there are a few other troubleshooting steps to try.

Comment: I do have firefox installed on my computer.