# Is it necessary to connect via Cisco VPN using my university account to go online?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, vpn, cisco

**Original title:**
Bug with Xisco VPN - it it necessary to connect via Cisco VPN using my university-account in order to go online for all wireless networks

---

In order to gain wireless access to my university network, I had to download and install the Cisco VPN client. It worked fine under 11.10 and did so for two weeks on 12.04. But since yesterday, I am unable to connect to my wireless network at home. First I have to connect via Cisco VPN using my university account. This is quite annoying and I'm unable to download apps via the software center when using the Cisco VPN client.

I really don't know what happened, because it worked fine for two weeks and I did not change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue. I uninstalled cisco-vpn and installed openconnect as mentioned in the following link. It worked.

- http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/06/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-to-cisco.html
- [Server certificate problem with Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129477/server-certificate-problem-with-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-client)